# How to pass environment variables to a script present in ConfigMap while accessing it as a volume in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, argo-workflows, argo

I have the following ConfigMap which is having a variable called `VAR`. This variable should get the value from the workflow while accessing it as a volume

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-pod-cfg
data:
  test-pod.yaml: |-
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      name: test-pod
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: test
          image: ubuntu
          command: ["/busybox/sh", "-c", "echo $VAR"]
```

Here is the argo workflow which is fetching script `test-pod.yaml` in ConfigMap and adding it as a volume to container. In this how to pass Environment variable `VAR` to the ConfigMap for replacing it dynamically

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  name: test-wf-
spec:
  entrypoint: main
  templates:
    - name: main
      container:
        image: "ubuntu"
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "cat /mnt/vc/test"]
        volumeMounts:
          - name: vc
            mountPath: "/mnt/vc"
      volumes:
        - name: vc
          configMap:
            name: test-pod-cfg
            items:
              - key: test-pod.yaml
                path: test
```

Comment: I was using an alternate way in my solution. So didn't check this answer. But the solution seems to be working. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mount the `ConfigMap` as a volume and make the environment variable VAR available to the container, you will need to add a volume to the pod's spec and set the environment variable in the container's spec.

In the volume spec, you will need to add the `ConfigMap` as a volume source and set the path to the file containing the environment variable. For example:

```
spec:
  entrypoint: test-pod
  templates:
  - name: test-pod
    container:
      image: ubuntu
      command: ["/busybox/sh", "-c", "echo $VAR"]
      volumeMounts:
      - name: config
        mountPath: /etc/config
      env:
      - name: VAR
        valueFrom:
          configMapKeyRef:
            name: test-pod-cfg
            key: test-pod.yaml
    volumes:
    - name: config
      configMap:
        name: test-pod-cfg
```

The environment variable `VAR` will then be available in the container with the value specified in the ConfigMap.

For more information follow this [official doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-container-environment-variables-with-data-from-multiple-configmaps).